# Program error: unwanted number in statement

Tags: c, primes

I am making a program where the user enters a positive integer between 2 and 1000000, and if it is a prime number it prints "The number is a prime number" and if it isn't a prime number it prints the factorization of the number. Whenever I input a prime number (ie: 3) it prints that it is a prime number, but then after the period it prints the number again (ie: The number 3 is a prime number.3). I can't seem to find why this is happening, does anyone know where I made an error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int N, i, div, flag=0;
printf("Please enter a positive integer: ");
scanf("%d",&N);
for(i=2;i<=N/2;++i)
{
  if(N%i==0)
  {
      flag=1;
      break;
  }
}
if (flag==0)
  printf("The number %d is a prime number.", N);
else
printf("The number %d is not a prime number.\nThe prime factors of %d              are:",N, N);

div = 2;

while(N!=0){
    if(N%div!=0)
        div = div + 1;
    else {
        N = N / div;
        printf("%d ",div);
        if(N==1)
            break;
    }
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given the code above, it's not possible that both `the number 3 is a prime number.` and `the number 3 is not a prime number` is printed.  Are you sure that your problem description is correct?

Comment: You could put the `else` clause between brackets and insert a `return` after the `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because even when its a prime number, the later `while` loop gets executed. And this prints `3`, which is by this statement

```
printf("%d ",div);
```

---

To stop this, you can add another check in the while loop, which will stop it from entering if its a prime number.

```
while(N!=0 && flag==1) //flag will be 1 if the number is not prime, and factors are present
```

---

Or, you can keep the other part in the `else statement, like

```
if (flag==0)
    printf("The number %d is a prime number.", N);
else
{
    printf("The number %d is not a prime number.\nThe prime factors of %d              are:",N, N);

    div = 2;

    while(N!=0){
        if(N%div!=0)
            div = div + 1;
        else {
            N = N / div;
            printf("%d ",div);
            if(N==1)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot brackets for your `else` statement. So the else (not a prime number) only applies to the `printf`.

The rest is always executed, wether it is or not a prime number.